# MySQL query to calculate distance between two coordinates but too slow with HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, having, having-clause

I have the following query that calculates the distance between two coordinates. However, I want to select the users that are within the range of `n` km. Say, for example, I want to select all users that are within a distance of 100km. Therefore, I have to use `HAVING` clause here. However, I see that the execution is damn too slow. Even with just two records it's returning the results very slowly. I wonder what would happen with a million user records (in future). Therefore, I am seeking an optimization to my current query for efficient and faster running.

```
SELECT *, 
  111.1111 *
  DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) 
  * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude)) 
  * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude) - RADIANS(b.longitude)) 
  + SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude))
  * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude))))) AS distance_in_km 
FROM users AS a
JOIN users AS b ON a.id <> b.id
WHERE b.id != :user AND a.id = :user 
HAVING distance_in_km < :maxdist 
LIMIT 30
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Rick James, I have removed `GROUP BY` clause and replaced it with `AND a.id = :user` in `WHERE` clause. This, as of now, is returning the same result as was with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: A small sample data of 10-20 rows would be helpful here.

Comment: This is a very thoroughly discussed topic!! Anyway, a couple of tips: 1. `WHERE 111.1111 *...` will likely be quicker than `HAVING distance`. 2. A bounding box is always a good idea.

Comment: Add WHERE which filters by one coordinate only (both Lat and Long are closer than 100 km).

Comment: See this for performance in "find nearest": http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql  Gordon's bounding box is an important component in all better-performing techniques.  `WHERE` is no better than `HAVING` because it still has to check all rows.

Comment: Don't you want an `ORDER BY`?  Else you are getting some random subset of those within 100 km.

Comment: I am okay with random users. In fact, that completely satisfies the purpose. I want to display all the random users who are within the range of 100km (for example) to the current logged in user. Therefore, `ORDER BY` is not necessary.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is ill-formed.  See `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: As written 1 million rows would require 1 _trillion_ distance computations.  Don't you need `AND a.id = :user` ?

Comment: @ShubhamJha - You don't need a self-join; just look through the table.  (Please clean up the various issues by modifying the Question; then I will address the responses.)

Comment: @RickJames I don't need `AND a.id = :user` as I do not want to show the logged in user. Only the other users who are within the range of 100km.

Comment: @ShubhamJha - Then let me put it this way -- the `GROUP BY` says "Look at ALL rows, then boil it down to one row."  That can be terribly costly.  So...  Toss the `GROUP BY` and add the `AND`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is that you cannot make your query more efficient.  For your approach, you basically need to calculate the distance between all pairs of users, and that is expensive.

There may be some hacks that you can use.  First, you probably don't need reversed pairs, so you can replace `a.id <> b.id` with `a.id < b.id`.  That will eliminate half the work.

You can use a `where` clause to pre-filter the rows.  For instance, on most of the earth's surface, points that are more than 2 degrees of latitude or longitude apart are more than 100 km apart.  *This is not true everywhere.*  But it is probably good enough for you.  That allows you to write:

```
where a.latitude between b.latitude - 2 and b.latitude + 2 and
      a.longitude between b.longitude - 2 and b.longitude + 2
```

That will save much of the trigonometry, if your users are spread far and wide.

However, the real solution is to use the GIS extensions of MySQL.  A place to start learning about that is in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html).

EDIT:

```
SELECT *,
   111.1111 *
   DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(b.latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude) - RADIANS(b.longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.latitude))))) AS distance_in_km
FROM users a JOIN
     users b
     ON a.id <> b.id
WHERE a.id = :user AND
      a.latitude between b.latitude - 2 and b.latitude + 2 and
      a.longitude between b.longitude - 2 and b.longitude + 2
HAVING distance_in_km < 100
```

Comment: On the longitude side, do `2 / cos(lat)` in order to adjust for the curvature of the earth.

Comment: I think I would need reversed pairs as user with id 10 should be compared with both less than 10 and more than 10. That is, user 10 should be compared with users 1-9 and 11,12,13,....n. Without reversed pairs, with what you have suggested (using a less than), here only compares with users those are less than the `a.id`. What's your take on this?

Comment: @RickJames I would request you to edit and update the answer :)

Comment: @ShubhamJha . . . Distance is symmetric, so I don't see why it is necessary to do the calculation twice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am a bit confused here using your sample with my query. Would it be too much if I ask you to edit the answer and post a complete code using my query so that it's more understandable on what I should eliminate and what I should keep? That would be a great help :)

Comment: @RickJames . . . I was actually trying to avoid trig functions.  Also, `cos(lat)` isn't sufficient, because `lat` isn't measured in radians.  And, my real point is that the OP should use a spatial index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - OK, `COS(RADIANS(lat))`.  Yes, `SPATIAL` is a good idea.  But it still needs a bounding box.

Comment: If you don't use `SPATIAL`, use `INDEX(lat, lng), INDEX(lng, lat)` as discussed here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Comment: @GordonLinoff - and toss `ON a.id < b.id` now that he has added `a.id=:user`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do what you want would be repeating the code on your `select` in the `where` section

```
SELECT *, 
   111.1111 *
   DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(b.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(a.Longitude) - RADIANS(b.Longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.Latitude))))) AS distance_in_km
FROM users AS a
  JOIN users AS b ON a.id <> b.id
WHERE
    111.1111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(b.Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(a.Longitude) - RADIANS(b.Longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
         * SIN(RADIANS(b.Latitude))))) < 100
```

Other option will be (better "look and feel", worse performance)

```
with d as (
    SELECT *, 
       111.1111 *
       DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
             * COS(RADIANS(b.Latitude))
             * COS(RADIANS(a.Longitude) - RADIANS(b.Longitude))
             + SIN(RADIANS(a.Latitude))
             * SIN(RADIANS(b.Latitude))))) AS distance_in_km
    FROM users AS a
      JOIN users AS b ON a.id <> b.id
)
select * from d
where d.distance_in_km > 100
```

Comment: Duplicating query this way and bulking out the code, do you really think it's a good idea and a right approach? Just confirming...

Comment: You have other ways, if you don't like this one, but they will force to query the same data twice. I can provide you one using `with`

Comment: There is no reason that either of these queries would be faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it was just a hunch... The first query go through the tables in the join section once. But the second query, once the first set of data is retrieved, must check the where condition on the `distance_in_km` attribute., cheking over the data built by the `with` section. So there is a reason on my comment and it's not just random.

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . The problem is that the OP needs to calculate the distance between all users.  Whether this uses a CTE or `WHERE` or `HAVING` might have a (very small) effect on the performance, but it does not reduce the overall work that needs to be done.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, being honest... I though the problem with the OP was related to the use of `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY` expression, that's why I directly recommended to move the filter to the `WHERE` section, but your answer is far way better to resolve the question of the OP.

Comment: @JaimeDrq I have updated the question with a `GROUP BY` clause. Please have a look now.

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . That is a MySQL extension.  It can have performance implications (i.e. prevents the use of indexes) but they are not relevant here.  It is one way that MySQL made it possible to avoid some derived tables, because those tend to be materialized which can have a big impact on performance.